# Is there a way to get a range object when selecting text with a keyboard?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, electron, keyboard

is it correct that in an electron app - or as far as I can see web-based applications in general - a range or selection object is not created when the text content is selected using a keyboard?

I am currently playing around creating a tool that is also as accessible as possible. That's why I wondered whether those informations (selection, range object ...) shoud not also be generated when using a keyboard, e.g. by blind users that can't use a mouse.

At the moment something along the lines of

```
this.state.currentLocation.selectionInfo.cleanText
```

returns `undefined`.

Has anyone got any advice how I could still get those informations?

**EDIT**

For clarification:
It's a reader application (open-source but not by myself) mainly for EPUBs. I've implemented a keyboard handler that is supposed to add a text input for the user to add an annotation when a text passage is selected and a keyboard shortcut is triggered.

```
this.addTextInputForAnnotation(annotationType, this.state.currentLocation.selectionInfo.cleanText, this.state.currentLocation.selectionInfo.rangeInfo.startContainerElementCssSelector, this.state.currentLocation.selectionInfo.rangeInfo.startOffset, this.state.currentLocation.selectionInfo.rangeInfo.endContainerElementCssSelector, this.state.currentLocation.selectionInfo.rangeInfo.endOffset);
```

The annotation type is determined by the explicit keyboard shortcut, the other parameters remain empty when the text is selected by keyboard not by mouse. This results in the error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'cleanText')
    at Object.Reader.onAddAnnotationImportant [as callback] (Reader.tsx:230:1)
```

`this` represents an instance of the Reader class in the application, declared like this:

```
class Reader extends React.Component<IProps, IState>
```

where `IProps` references the data types of the components of state.

The state is initiated this way:

```
this.state = {
            ...

            mediaOverlaysState: MediaOverlaysStateEnum.STOPPED,
            mediaOverlaysPlaybackRate: "1",

            visibleBookmarkList: [],
            currentLocation: undefined,

            divinaNumberOfPages: 0,
            divinaReadingModeSupported: [],

            ...
        };
```

Comment: Perhaps if you'd provide some minimum example code...

Comment: @vanowm hope I' ve made my issue more clear

Comment: It is not really, because we have no idea what `this` is...

Comment: @vanowm i've added it the way i understand it